# Writing to a json file in workspace using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've a jenkins job with few parameters setup and I've a JSON file in the workspace which has to be updated with the parameters that I pass through jenkins.

Example:

I have the following parameters which I'll take input from user who triggers the job:

- Environment (Consider user selects "ENV2")
- Filename (Consider user keeps the default value)

I have a json file in my workspace under run/job.json with the following contents:

```
{
    environment: "ENV1",
    filename: "abc.txt"
}
```

Now whatever the value is given by user before triggering a job has to be replaced in the job.json.

So when the user triggers the job, the job.json file should be:

```
{
    environment: "ENV2",
    filename: "abc.txt"
}
```

Please note the environment value in the json which has to be updated.

I've tried https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin plugin. But I'm unable to find any help on parameterizing the values.

Kindly suggest on configuring this plugin or suggest any other plugin which can serve my purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Config File Provider Plugin doesn't allow you to pass parameters to configuration files. You can solve your problem with any scripting language. My favorite approach is using [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). Hit a check-box "Execute system Groovy script" and paste the following script:

```java
import groovy.json.*

// read build parameters
env = build.getEnvironment(listener)
environment = env.get('environment')
filename = env.get('filename')

// prepare json
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder environment: environment, filename: filename
json = builder.toPrettyString()

// print to console and write to a file
println json
new File(build.workspace.toString() + "\\job.json").write(json)
```

Output sample:

```
{
    "environment": "ENV2",
    "filename": "abc.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin) plugin this is very easy to achieve.

```groovy
    jsonfile = readJSON file: 'path/to/your.json'
    jsonfile['environment'] = 'ENV2'
    writeJSON file: 'path/to/your.json', json: jsonfile
```

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for execute you example?

Answer (score 0):

I will keep it simple. A windows batch file or a shell script (depending on the OS) which will read the environment values and open the JSON file and make the changes.

Comment: I have that in my mind. But would like to see an easiest and better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's comment was correct, however he forgot about returnPojo field. Here's updated example:

```
jsonfile = readJSON file: 'path/to/your.json', returnPojo: true
jsonfile['environment'] = 'ENV2'
writeJSON file: 'path/to/your.json', json: jsonfile
```