# Get parameters passed to different Job Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I want to get the parameters from another job similarly how we copy artifacts from another job.

Ex:
Consider 2 jenkins jobs A and B.
Job A has build #30 which produces .zip artifact.

My Requirement:
I want Job B to have all parameters passed to build #30 in Job A.
(I am using Copy artifacts plugin to copy .zip from #30 of Job A)
How to get parameters from different jenkins job?

Comment: How is Job B triggered? Automatically? By Job A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking the parameters from injectedEnvVars.txt of the respective job.( grep the specific like with the keyword and get the value)

something like this:
Release_Number=`cat $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$ProjectName/builds/$BuildNumber/injectedEnvVars.txt | grep Release | cut -d'=' -f 2`

This gives me the value of parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Write a batch\shell script that creates a json file including all parameters and their values. The script will be executed as separate build step in job A. Mark the resulting file as artifact.

You can access the file in job B via the copy artifacts plugin as you are already using it.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31532135/1586762) is an example of such script using Groovy.