# How can I create a dot file in the workspace from the jenkins job

Tags: linux, bash, docker, jenkins, dotfiles

I have a jenkins job that amongst other things I want to dynamically create a `.foo` and a `.bar` file in my jenkins workspace home directory as the job is running.

How can I do that with bash as a part of the job?

The job will run after a Docker container has been created with the Docker Plugin.

So the order of precedence I want is :

Job starts:

1. docker container get's created
2. create .foo file (and enter foobarbaz as a content in the file)
3. create .bar file (and enter foobarbaz as a content in the file)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to associate your Jenkins job with a source controlled repository URL, which already include the files with the right content.

Each job execution would create a workspace populated with that repo content, and launch your docker container.

If not, you would need to add a script step, like [this one in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532135/6309).